# will sudo apt-get upgrade destroy my python 2 environment?

Tags: python, sudo, conda

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. I have just installed conda with python3 and python2 environments. I also see people say "sudo apt-get upgrade" will upgrade all packages installed. My concern is that will it upgrade the python2 package in the second env? If so, wouldn't this line of command very destructive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No not, If you use conda it is on their environment which conda mantain. Python 2 will be upgraded to latest python 2 version and not deleted and upgraded to python 3 because some apps still runs on it. `apt upgrade` will upgrade your conda not the environment you setup.